# Intercept an url with a given domain in the Android, iOS and Javascript ports of a Codename One app

Tags: codenameone

**Use case**: I need to replicate the way used by popular social networks to provide a link to a given content, like a post. That means that a link like https://www.example.com/link-to-the-content should be intercepted by Android, iOS and Javascript ports of a Codename One app.

I tried to do that, without success.

**Javascript port**
I don't know if the `Display.getInstance().getProperty("AppArg", null);` is implemented in any way in the javascript port. I understood that if the javascript port is installed in https://www.example.com/, then https://www.example.com/link-to-the-content will produce a 404 error. However I suppose that this restriction can be circumvented implementing some server code (that could be automatically included in the `war` produced by the build server)... or, without any special server code, if the url is like https://www.example.com/?content=xyz, maybe the `Display.getInstance().getProperty("AppArg", null);` can be used. Please let me known if there is any already working solution or if it is necessary a RFE.

**Android Port**
This is partially working for me, is there something wrong in my code? The problem is that it works fine if the app is killed and then opened from a link, but it doesn't work if the app is opened from the icon, then it is putted in background and then it is opened again from the link: in this case, the app will show a blank white screen.

My build hint for Android:
`android.xintent_filter=<intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /><category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /><category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /><data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="https" /></intent-filter>`

Code:

```
public class MyApplication {

private Form current;
private Resources theme;
private String arg;

public void init(Object context) {
    [...]
}

public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());

    final SpanLabel message;
    arg = Display.getInstance().getProperty("AppArg", null);
    if (arg == null) {
        message = new SpanLabel("App launched from icon");
    } else {
        message = new SpanLabel("App launched from the url: " + arg);
    }
    hi.add(message);
    hi.show();

    hi.addShowListener(l -> {
        arg = Display.getInstance().getProperty("AppArg", null);
        if (arg == null) {
            message.setText("App launched from icon");
        } else {
            message.setText("App launched from the url: " + arg);
        }
        hi.revalidate();
    });

}
```

**iOS port**
This doesn't work at all for me. I tried to use the build hint `ios.urlScheme=<string>example.com</string>`, but the urls like https://www.example.com/link-to-the-content are not intercepted. I guess that `ios.urlScheme=<string>example.com</string>` is used to specify the protocol instead of the domain, but I don't know which build hint I have to write to intercept any url with a given domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android and iOS you need a custom URL scheme e.g. these are the build hints for the Codename One Build app:

```
android.xintent_filter=<intent-filter>   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />    <data android:scheme="cn1bldapp" />  </intent-filter>
ios.plistInject=<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>     <array>         <dict>             <key>CFBundleURLName</key>             <string>com.codename1.build.app</string>         </dict>         <dict>             <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>             <array>                 <string>cn1bldapp</string>             </array>         </dict>     </array>
```

For these build hints you can use a URL that looks like this:

```
cn1bldapp://content-of-the-url
```

Unfortunately this will only partially work because most places won't recognize cn1bldapp as a URL. But here's the trick as [I explained here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-activate-via-url-send-arguments.html), you can use an https URL and then redirect using a 302 response to the cn1bldapp. This way you can also detect the referring caller and send the right URL response if they differ.

About the JavaScript port I think you can probably pass a URL argument using the `#` option then query that in JS using the location but there might be a more elegant approach to pass that or do deep linking. I'll have to check on that.

Comment: You can retrieve the `#` option in the js port with the `browser.window.location.hash` display property.

Comment: Thank you both Shai and Steve, however I asked to intercept urls with a standard protocol (https) and a custom domain, that is the way used for example by Facebook. When the user click on that kind of links, the smartphone should offer the choice to open the link with a browser or with my app. What you described (a custom protocol) is more useful for email activation or similar things, instead I need to offer the same content in a browser or inside the app, exactly as Facebook, StackOverflow and other socials.

Comment: Moreover, I copied and pasted in my question a not properly working code. I described a condition in which I get a blank white screen, what's why I asked if there is something wrong in my code.

Comment: I think we can continue that here https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2581for other people reading this